# On disconnecting ChromeCast from one device it is getting disconnected from both android devices

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Two devices are connected to a Chromecast receiver and disconnecting from one also disconnects the other device. Recently upgraded the SDK version to 9.8.0 and post that only this issue got visible. Any insights for this?

Comment: How are you "disconnecting" your first device?

Comment: Using the stop casting button from the dialog

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at your receiver app and see what logic you are using there that could cause this behavior. On the receiver side,  `onSenderDisconnected()` is called when a sender disconnects and at that point, you need to see if there is any other connected sender left there and only if there is none, you should close the receiver. You can take a look at the reference receiver sample to see how that can be done, or read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#session-management). If you are using the Default or a Styled receiver, then you need to make sure that you are not calling `stopApplication()` from your sender side.

Comment: We are not using Default or styled receiver instead a custom receiver is in place. The suggestion regarding onSenderDisconnected() is already in place with the necessary checks. In fact the same scenario is not visible in iOS app.

Comment: Then make sure you are doing the right thing on the sender side. Look at the call hierarchy on your sender when you press "Stop Casting".

Comment: This is also visible in the sample app castVideos-android by using the library version 9.8.0.

Comment: I tried and it is not the case (I tried with the latest cast sdk: 10.0.1); sample app behaves correctly.

Comment: Will check the same with new sdk version

Comment: Tried with the sample app by changing the sdk version to 10.0.1 as follows compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.0.1'. The issue is visible now also while running the sample in two devices and disconnecting from one.

Comment: Have debugged the receiver side too and senderId is always the same even though the multiple devices got connected over the same Chromecast receiver. The castVideos-android is also having the same problem, connect multiple android devices to same receiver and disconnect from anyone device. This will close the receiver and connection is getting stopped from all devices.

Comment: Issue addressed in Google Cast SDK forum https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1064

Comment: Still not solved. Unreal... @AliNaddaf You working on the SDK? Please fix this :D