# How to stop sender to tear down the receiver so that other senders can keep casting?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm having trouble when two senders are casting to the same chromecast and when one of the senders stops casting, all of them stops too. I can't find anywhere in the documentation how to override the stop function in Cast V3.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:
It´s a duplicate of this [On disconnecting ChromeCast from one device it is getting disconnected from both android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256136/on-disconnecting-chromecast-from-one-device-it-is-getting-disconnected-from-both)

Thanks too this I´ve come one step closer to solve it. The devices share the same session id, anybody that got an idea why?

Comment: duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256136/on-disconnecting-chromecast-from-one-device-it-is-getting-disconnected-from-both

Comment: Searched for hours without finding anything... Need to up my game in searching, thanks! Unfortunately the question you linked does not have an answer. But I made me come one step closer, the devices share the same session id, any input on that?

Answer (score 0):

In V3, when you configure CastOptions, there is a setting that tells the framework whether you want the sender app to stop the receiver when disconnecting or leave that up to the receiver: [`CastOptions.Builder#setStopReceiverApplicationWhenEndingSession()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastOptions.Builder.html#setStopReceiverApplicationWhenEndingSession(boolean))

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've not implemented that setting and it says in the documentation that by default it should be false. But I tried it anyway and it did not help me. As I wrote in the edit the devices gets same session id, I'm guessing that it's not supposed to do that. Do you have any input on that?

Comment: Devices should have different deviceIds; there is only one session at a time so sessionId should be the same for all of them. What receiver are you using? Is it custom?

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, it is a custom receiver. The code that checks if there is zero senders left then tear down the receiver is implemented so that should not be any problem.

Comment: @DanijelKljakic Did you ever fix this problem? From what I can tell, custom receivers suffer from this bug.

Comment: Hey @l33t, I'm sorry but this was so long time ago and for a project that I'm since a long time ago no longer involved with that I don't remember anything almost. I remember that it was a custom receiver also but I can't for the life of me remember if we solved it or accepted this issue. I should've updated this question 5 years ago...